# Как создать gzip архив в памяти

Tags: php, gzip

Скрипт генерирует контент на основе данных из базы (предположим это выгрузка в формате csv). Хотелось бы применить архивирование к результату, но так, чтобы не создавать временных файлов на диске.

Возможно ли это осуществить в памяти и как?

Пока делается так:

```
final class ClassPrefixGzipStream extends ClassPrefixStream
{
    private $handle;

    final public function open()
    {
        $this->handle = gzopen(TEMP_PATH . $this->uniqueID, "w9");
    }

    final public function write($string)
    {
        gzwrite($this->handle, $string);
    }

    final public function close()
    {
        gzclose($this->handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте метод [`gzdeflate()`](http://php.net/gzdeflate)

> This function compress the given
> string using the DEFLATE data format.
>
> For details on the DEFLATE compression
> algorithm see the document ["DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification version 1.3"](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951) (RFC 1951).

Comment: Правильно ли я понял: можно тогда и gzcompress? У меня догадка, что это мне не подойдет. Заня примерный принцип работы архиваторов, активнее будет, если архивируется весь файл целиком, нежели по отдельности. Мне бы хотелось создать файл в памяти и потом весь послать его в архив. К примеру fopen('php://memory','r+') или fopen('php://temp/mamemory:4096','r+')...

Comment: Да, можно и gzcompress(). А что значит активнее? Сжатие должно быть быстрее, выше компрессия или ниже потребление ресурсов CPU? Какая именно характеристика вас беспокоит?

---

Я думаю, результат с php://memory принципиально не будет ничем отличатся. Если уже хочется архивировать уже конечный файл, то самый простой способ воспользоваться [tmpfs][1], во многих дистрибутивах он по умолчанию смонтирован в /dev/shm

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: Мне хочется на лету отдавать сжатый файл на лету, без использования временных файлов. А если я буду использовать gzcompress, то выигрышь будет не лучшим, потому как смогу подсовывать ему порции от 5 до 40 байт из мегабайтного файла. Поэтому хочется все сразу скормить.

Comment: Что мешает накапливать порции в буфере до необходимого объема? Или использовать уже готовый [ob_gzhandler][1]?

  [1]: http://php.net/ob-gzhandler

Comment: Человек хочет писать сжатые данные прямо в output stream. Это достаточно эффективно.

Comment: Хочется получить общую технологию, потому как по одному алгоритму будут и zip & gzip & standart io выполняться. Про ob_gzhandler - беру на заметку, смотрю.

Comment: Можно писать [обработчики буферизованного вывода][1], со своей логикой сжатия.

  [1]: http://php.net/ob-start